# What do the numbers after the HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.0 status codes signify?

Tags: apache-2.4, log-files

What are the numbers after the 200, 300, ... status codes and how can I find information about those numbers?

For example the numbers 2176, 30125 and 6566 below:

```
62.240.134.168 - - [04/Oct/2022:09:27:45 +0200] "GET /CSSSamples.css HTTP/2.0" 200 2176 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; motorola one macro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
62.240.134.168 - - [04/Oct/2022:09:27:41 +0200] "GET /jquery.min.js HTTP/2.0" 200 30125 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; motorola one macro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
134.209.144.78 - - [04/Oct/2022:05:51:13 +0200] "GET /ab2g HTTP/1.1" 404 6566 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is number of bytes in the response per [apache's documentation on its log format](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)...

> A typical configuration for the access log might look as follows.
>
> ```
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
> CustomLog logs/access_log common
> ```
>
> The above configuration will write log entries in a format known as the Common Log Format (CLF). This standard format can be produced by many different web servers and read by many log analysis programs. The log file entries produced in CLF will look something like this:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
> ```
>
> ...
>
> 2326 (%b)
> The last part indicates the size of the object returned to the client, not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value will be "-". To log "0" for no content, use %B instead.

Comment: the size...omg. thx